# ADD() - AMPscript to add multiple number

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a lovely AMPscript function for adding 2 numbers together.

Add(N1,N2)

However what if I want to add 4?
I've tried it in ExactTarget and it give me an error that I can only add 2 numbers.
Obviously I can try (x + y) + (a + b) but at the end I will need to add up about 12 numbers. (this is going to be a receipt of a purchase email)

Is there any way to add multiple (more than 2) numbers so I will not need to create a vastly complicated and long AMPscript line?

Comment: How are you generating each line in that receipt? The typical approach to this is to have a running total - that is, after every output/print of an amount, you'd add it to a variable. This way, at the end, the variable's value is equal to the total.

Comment: thanks for the input edu8rdo. whats the upside of having a running total instead of just adding everything up at the end?

the numbers for each item in the receipt is coming from another system. And all I need to do is to put in the attribute at the end of each line. (promo prices are coming as a full number also and not as like -20%)

Comment: Hi Balint - just to clarify, I don't mean you should have a display of the running total in the email/receipt, but instead added to a variable during every iteration of the line items. Below in the answers section, @ryan-bridges covers the idea way to do this - via a loop. However, if I'm reading your question and follow up correctly, it sounds like there's a different column for each number? Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have your numbers coming in you could possibly create a loop and add the next number to the running total:

```
%%[
    VAR @array, @rows, @i, @row, @value, @total
    SET @total = 0 
    SET @array = Concat(1, "|", 3, "|", 10, "|", 33, "|", 27, "|", 9) 
    SET @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@array, '|')
    FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) DO 
        SET @row = Row(@rows, @i) 
        SET @value = Field(@row,1)
        SET @total = Add(@total, @value)
    NEXT @i
]%%

%%=v(@total)=%%
```

An alternative would be use Server-Side Javascript.  That seems like it would be a lot easier for this situation.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Could you expand your answer with more information or snippets describing how you would "create a loop" or use "Server-Side Javascript"

Comment: Sure @Benj!  I'm not sure how Balint is pulling the numbers, so I'll illustrate with an array, then build a rowset from the array, then iterate through the values adding them. `%%[
VAR @array, @rows, @i, @row, @value, @total
SET @total = 0
SET @array = Concat(1, "|", 3, "|", 10, "|", 33, "|", 27, "|", 9)
SET @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@array, '|')

FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) DO
    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @value = Field(@row,1)
    SET @total = Add(@total, @value)
NEXT @i
]%%
%%=v(@total)=%%`

Comment: Sorry for the ugly formatting - I'm new to posting on SFSE. That's the AMPscript version. The numbers I have in the array are just examples and the script will end up giving you a total of whatever is in there. For SSJS it's just javascript adding them together `total = a + b + c + d + e;`

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Bridges.  One of the great things about SFSE is that you can actually go back and edit your posts, so I went ahead and included your code sample directly in the answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @Benj.  That's much better.  And thanks for the pointers!